# Problem with img reference in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hello i tried to build docker-compose in my project with these structure file:

```
app/
   -front-end/src/Components
   -back-end/images
```

but when i run build i have these error with img relative url:

```
frontend_1  | Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../../back-end/images'
```

And these is my docker-compose file:

```
  version: '2'
  services:
   backend:
    network_mode: host
    build: ./back-end/
    ports:
      - "6200:6200"
    volumes:
      - ./back-end:/usr/src/app
  frontend:
    build: ./front-end/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./front-end:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

My frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.3
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /TuKanasta

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

the backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.3
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /TuKanasta

RUN npm install -g nodemon

EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Note: My project run 100 % without docker.

Answer (score 1):

```
volumes:
      - ./back-end:/usr/src/app
...
volumes:
      - ./front-end:/usr/src/app
```

If set in the same image, the second bind mount volume would overwrite the first `/usr/src/app` content, as illustrated in [`gladiusio/gladius-archive-node` issue 4](https://github.com/gladiusio/gladius-archive-node/issues/4).

If set in two different images, `/usr/src/app` in `frontend1` would not be able to see `back-end`, copied in `/usr/src/app` *separate* volume of `backend` service.

[Declaring the volume as `external`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) might help, as illustrated in [this thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/attach-docker-volume-using-docker-compose/47582).
Or copying into an existing volume ([shown here](https://forums.docker.com/t/making-volumes-with-docker-compose/45657/2))

Comment: I don't think what you said is right . he is building 2 different images starting FROM node:10.15.3   which means he will build 2 different images starting from the same image  the first and the second  volumes will run in 2 different containers  the issue you specified speaks about a building an image with a file inside it then using the image built and override the file with the mounted volume

Comment: @MontassarBouagina If that is the case, (2 different images, each one with their own volume), wouldn't that mean frontend_1 cannot find backend in its own frontend_1/usr/src/app volume? That would also explain the error message in the OP.

Comment: Yes this is the problem he is trying to access the ./back-end/images  from the frontend image  :)

Comment: @MontassarBouagina OK, makes sense. I have edited the answer to make the flawed usecase more apparent.